# Interstitials admob android webview

Tags: android, webview, admob, ads, interstitial

Hello i got a webview project.I wanna add interstitials ads for my project.i have a banner ads but i wanna add one more full screen ads.how can i do this ? anyone help me ? my xml have a only webview (webView) and ads (adsView).thanks all right.

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail?

Comment: Yes I want add interstitial ads.i got publisher Id by admob.im doing required ads comments but it's not doing.u got teamviewer u can connect my pc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following lines of code in your activity

```
   interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
  interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6046034785851961/xxxxxx");

   // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

     // Begin loading your interstitial.
     interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


      interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
      public void onAdLoaded(){
           displayInterstitial();
      }
      });
```

Comment: the now what is the status??

Comment: AdRequest.Builder giving error.Eclipse offer Fix Project Setup when i pressed it.opening JAR library.i added gooogle ads SDK ?

Comment: yaa you should add add sdk

Comment: Can u give me SDK link for interstitial I had for banners ☺ ?

Comment: anyone help ?  i need help :S

Comment: u here ? maybe u wanna help to me :) ?